# How to build Boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost, build, libraries

I wanted to use boost::program_options. After I installed boost, I think that I have to build separatly program_options (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). But I don't know how to do it.

I am trying to compile the C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_42\libs\program_options\example\first.cpp (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html) but probably due to I didn't build the library I have this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc90-mt-gd-1_42.lib'
```

**EDIT**: I used the installers supplied by BoostPro Computing so I skipped the installation of the binaries (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#install-visual-studio-binaries)

**EDIT**: I also followed the instructions at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide

Comment: Why did you skip installation of the binaries? That's the very part you need...

Comment: Do you have any libraries (files named *.lib) in your C:\Program Files\boost?

Comment: Compilation instructions are given in **section 5** of the document you linked to. Which part did you have trouble with? (If you just ask how to compile, the only answer you'll get is to follow those instructions. If you need more specific help, ask a more specific question.)

Comment: @jpalecek I didn't skip the installation of the binaries. I skipped next step, following the instructions:

 Install Visual Studio Binaries

The installers supplied by BoostPro Computing will download and install pre-compiled binaries into the lib\ subdirectory of the boost root, typically C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_43_0\lib\. If you installed all variants of the Boost.Regex binary, you're done with this step. Otherwise, please run the installer again and install them now.
- skip to the next step -

Comment: @Rob Kennedy I followed step 5.1 Install Visual Studio Binaries

Answer (score 3):

After reading the [Boost 1.54 Getting Started on Windows guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) these are the steps that you should take ([`program_options` is a header only library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries)). You need to have a MSVC compiler installed.

1. [Download Boost's source code from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.54.0/) and install it.
2. From a command line (preferably the Developer Command Prompt for VS):

   `bootstrap.bat`

   `bjam.exe --build-type=complete msvc stage --with-program_options`

This will finish in a couple of minutes and that's it! The libraries are located in the directory `.\bin.v2\libs\program_options\build`.

BTW you could see which libraries you can build using `bjam --show-libraries`.

Comment: this answer is a good one, for latest boost b2 is now the executable over bjam

Answer (score 1):

I've followed [these steps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source) and it worked pretty well. That is to build the few boost libraries that must be built separately.

I suggest you read the entire document.

Comment: Do you mean:
bootstrap
.\bjam
??

I have no bootstrap, neither bjam.

Comment: There is a .bat in boost's directory (probably called bootstrap.bat) you have to run it and it'll build bjam. bjam will build the libraries for you. btw you need to open the command prompt this way : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-from-the-command-prompt

Comment: @f4: Not if you use the BoostPro installers.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use precompiled binaries, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.boostpro.com/products/free).

And make sure to set the library path in your VC project to point to boost libraries.

Comment: Yes, that's the site where I downloaded http://www.boostpro.com/download/boost_1_42_setup.exe
Into my project I followed the instructions:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide

Answer (score 0):

Using CLion and CMake, I added the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

`target_link_libraries(myapp boost_program_options)`